# How to upload a profile picture to parse ionic framework

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ionic-framework, image-uploading

I was having a problem uploading a html 5, base64 image, to parse. I have a couple parse users created and a profile_pic column. Also I have included the cordovacamera plugin to select an image from the gallery and display it, but I now want to upload the image to the current users profile_pic column.

```
$scope.takePicture = function(){
    var options = {
      quality: 100,   
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    }
   $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
     .then(function(data){
        console.log('camera date: '+ angular.toJson(data));
        $scope.pictureUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        currentUser.set("profile_pic", data);
        currentUser.save();

     }, function(error) {
        console.log('camera error: '+ angular.toJson(data));
     });
  };
```

Is it possible to do or is there any other methods in which I can use?
I was able to successfully retrieve an image within the column and display the users profile pic, however I am in need of an uploading method.

```
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    currentUser.fetch().then(function (fetchedUser) {
    var name = fetchedUser.getUsername();
    var loca = fetchedUser.get('location');
    var propic = fetchedUser.get('profile_pic');
    var proimage = propic.url();
    $scope.username = name;
    $scope.location = loca;
    $scope.profilepic = proimage;
});
```

Comment: you have to  use $cordovafiletransfer.upload method to upload an image in your specific location

Comment: how does $cordovafiletransfer.upload work with parse?

Answer (score 0):

full source here https://github.com/aaronksaunders/dcww/blob/master/www/js/services.js#L33

But the basic concept is to create a File Object to save to the specific column in the user object.

```
var imageFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", {base64: _params.photo});
imageFile.save().then(function(_f) {
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  currentUser.set("profile_pic", data);
  return currentUser.save();
}).then(function(_user){
  return _user;
}, function(_error){
  console.log(_error);
};
```

Comment: unfortunately the console.log states error 481316 Reference Error_params is not defined. Sorry I'm fairly new to javascript and ionic have done a lot more with php but is there a resolution for this?

Comment: It was not meant to work since there is so much of your code missing... It is an example code snippet... There is a complete functioning solution linked included